# How to recognize this string encrpytion?

Tags: delphi, encryption, delphi-7

server=837858331746934658232248630236935288281180421

database=3386071348869302078373769320683350673360583083

username=3275115374797048

password=830105037835230605335414837835034204884870173

program using config.ini, it written by delphi. how can i decrypt this code, sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Do you have the source code for the delphi program that uses this config data? If so, start debugging it. Print out the values after the delphi program decrypts them.

Comment: Simple answer: you have to know how it was encrypted originally, or how those strings were created (not necessarily encryption). There is no information to go by from this snippet to deduce how it was encrypted or ciphered or anything.

Comment: i haven't got source code, how can i debug it? which program is better ?

Comment: If you don't have the source code, you can try sniffing the network traffic as the program runs and look for database credentials.

Comment: but i want to change this values

Comment: @birryree: I disagree. It's not easy to see whether there is enough information here. Cryptanalysis is a complex matter, and history has shown that allegedly secure cyphers could be broken. To start with, it is suspicious that the above cipher is completely numeric and probably certain sequences of numbers are more likely than others.

Comment: i can't contact with developer, i changed server and the program doesnt work. i must change this values please help me.

Comment: @birryree: not really. Even without statistical analysis it obvious what these messages' alphabet is {0..9}.

Comment: @özer özay, try known-plaintext with 1-2 character strings

Comment: @özer özay: This may very well end up being a "lesson learned" situation.  Using unsupported software for important things is ill-advised.

Answer (score 1):

As Asaph suggests in a comment, sniffing the network traffic with something like WireShark may yield the information you need.

Additionally (and I've never done this or used this tool yet, so this is mostly a guess), you may be able to use WinDbg or something like it to see raw strings in the application's memory space.

**Edit:** Ah, based on your recent comment, you want to supply new encrypted strings for the application.  That's a whole different ballgame.  Am I to assume that this application is in plain old Delphi and not Delphi .NET?  If the latter, disassembling the code is trivial.  But if the former, you may be out of luck.

Unless you can find something in the application that you haven't shared with us, or unless you can find a decompiler for Delphi, it sounds like an undocumented feature is preventing the application from being configured properly.  Can you contact the developer who wrote it?  Is it still supported?  Any documentation at all?

Answer (score 1):

Building on David's answer... 
You should be able to attack the program at the point where the strings are decrypted, and discover the values. Use a debugger or cracking tool, similar to the way that they go after shareware registration keys. There used to be an excellent tutorial on how to crack ClipMate5 and discover the key generation, and the cracker spoke highly of ClipMate 5 and how useful it was to him. (I wrote ClipMate5 so I remember that pretty well). 
But anyway, when you get to that point, you should be able to devise a patch where you can modify the code slightly to ignore the decrypted values and inject your own.
Of course, you should only do this if you are legally allowed to use the software, etc., etc., and there are unusual circumstances (programmer is dead, out of business, etc..).  Finally, consult with your lawyer, and your mother. If both agree that you're in the clear, you should be ok.